# JIRA API: How to update test result using Version and Test Cycle?

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-zephyr

Could someone share the steps and code that would allow me to update a test cycle for a given release?  I can get it to update the test results for Ad Hoc, but that is not what I want.  Here is what I have:

```
// 1. Get IssueId via "jira/rest/api/2/issue/" + issueKey
// 2. Get VersionId via "jira/rest/api/2/project/" + projectId + "/versions"
// 3. Get ProjectId via "jira/rest/api/2/project"
// 4. Create ExecutionId via "jira/rest/zapi/latest/execution", with issueId, projectId in header
// 5. Execute execution via "jira/rest/zapi/latest/execution" + executionId + "/execution" , with body containing status = 1 or 2
```

I have VersionId, but where do I put it?
I need to get TestCycle Id, but I cannot figure out where to get it, and once I get it, where do i put it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test Cycles are organised by version and project in Zephyr for JIRA.So, you should make the below GET request to get cycle id's for a given version of the selected project.

```
GET -  http://<jira_server>/rest/zapi/latest/cycle?projectId=10000&versionId=10100
```

With the above request you will get the cycleId, use this id in Execution Resource API "http://jira_server/rest/zapi/latest/execution" as below to get Execution Id's present in that cycle.

```
POST - http://<jira_server>/rest/zapi/latest/execution

HEADERS
Content-Type:application/json

BODY
{
  "issueId": 10600,
  "versionId": "10000",
  "cycleId": "16",
  "projectId": 10000
}
```

Now, use the executionId's as {id} in the below API to update the test result http:///rest/zapi/latest/execution/{id}/execute

**Usage**

```
PUT 
http://<jira_server>/rest/zapi/latest/execution/{id}/execute

HEADERS
Content-Type:application/json

BODY
{
  "status": "1"
}

Response
200
```

If you still face any issues sign up to our support site "https://support.getzephyr.com/hc/en-us" using your company email id and use the option "Submit a Case" to raise a ticket with us and one of our support engineers would immediately contact you. It's a better channel to keep track of Zephyr issues.

Comment: {
   "-1":
   {
       "totalExecutions": 0,
       "endDate": "",
       "description": "",
       "totalExecuted": 0,
       "started": "",
       "expand": "executionSummaries",
       "projectKey": "DSL",
       "versionId": 32205,
       "environment": "",
       "build": "",
       "ended": "",
       "name": "Ad hoc",
       "modifiedBy": "",
       "projectId": 21008,
       "startDate": "",
       "executionSummaries":
       {
           "executionSummary":
           [
           ]
       }
   },
   "recordsCount": 1

Comment: I did not get cycle Id after using get -  http://<jira_server>/rest/zapi/latest/cycle?projectId=10000&versionId=10100

Comment: If you hit on : https://<your jira url>/jira/rest/zapi/latest/execution/<execution id> you will get a json. Search for cycleId tag

Comment: Can we upload zip file as test result using version and test cycle?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by looking at the zapi documentation, i was incorrectly looking at the REST API documentation and couldn't find it there, not realizing test cycle is Zephyr solution. The request is supposed to look something like this:

```
https://jira.xxxxx.com/jira/rest/zapi/latest/cycle?{"versionId":12345,"projectId":12345}
```